# asp.net code first automatic database updates

Tags: database, frameworks, entity

I am creating an application in C# Asp.net using Code First Entity Framework that will be using a different databases for different customers (in other words every customer has its own database, that will be generated on first time use).

I am trying to figure out a way to update all these databases automatically whenever I apply changes to my objects. In other words, how would I approach a cleanstep system in Code First EF?

- Currently I am using InitializerIfModelChange to define a simple database that allows me to test my application whenever a schema change occurs. However, this method drops the database, which obviously is unacceptable in case of customer databases.
- I must assume hundreds of customers so updating all databases by hand is not an option
- I do not mind writing code that copies the data into a new database.

I think the best solution would be a way to backup a database somehow and then reinsert all data into the newly created database. Even better would be a way that automatically updates the schema without dropping the database. However I have no idea how to approach this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: is this what you need? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/02/09/ef-4-3-automatic-migrations-walkthrough.aspx

Comment: yes thats what I need thanks. Follow up question: How can I run Update-Database from code? I need a reference to HttpContext when generating the DbContext

Answer (score 0):

The link posted by Joakim was helpful. It requires you to update to EF 4.3.1 (dont forget your references in other projects if you have them) after which you can run the command that enables the migration. To automatically update the schema from code you can use

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(configuration);
migrator.Update();
Database.SetInitializer<DbContext>(null);
```